# bash script to that takes filename as argument and creates backup files

Tags: bash, shell

i m trying to bash script that takes filename as argument and The file given as argument would contain absolute path of files / folders in current system.
For example given filename as argument is 1.txt. If you cat 1.txt It will have the below paths

```
/etc/host
/var/lib/mysql
/home/user/Desktop
```

Now i want to copy all the files in those paths to another directory. And the given filename argument may have different paths. I just want to copy all those files in the paths to 'backup' directory.

Comment: how about: `rsync -nav \`cat 1.txt\` destination/.` also, `man rsync` and use `/` to search for what `-n` does.

Comment: can u put command please. No idea with rync

Comment: the command is: `rsync -av \`cat 1.txt\` destination/.` this will copy all of the paths in `1.txt` to `destination`. make sure that the paths in `1.txt` don't have no spaces or funny characters, and that there aren't hundreds of them.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be:

```
while read -r line; do cp -a "$line" /folder/backup; done < /folder/1.txt
```

The `cp -a` command is meant for archiving and preserves all permissions of the file/folder.